# Recurrence Relation with $n^{\frac{1}{2^k}}$ Square Root

Tags: recurrence-relations

I tried to solve this recurrence relation, like the following:

$$
\\
T(n) =
\begin{cases}
T(\sqrt[2]{n}) + c, & \text{if }n \geq 2 \\
a, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\\\\
T(n) = T(\sqrt[2]{n}) + c
\\
T(n) = T(\sqrt[4]{n}) + c + c = T(\sqrt[2^2]{n}) + 2c
\\
T(n) = T(\sqrt[8]{n}) + c + c + c = T(\sqrt[2^3]{n}) + 3c
\\
...
\\
T(n) = T(\sqrt[2^k]{n}) + kc = T(n^{\frac{1}{2^k}}) + kc
$$

The predicament is at the base case solving:

Using $n^{\frac{1}{2^k}} = 1$, it gets nowhere. Also, using $n^{\frac{1}{2^k}} = 2$ doesn't yield any interesting outcome.

Comment: In your last line of equations, where does the $\displaystyle 2^{\frac{1}{2^k}}$ come from? (You need to find the smallest $k$ such that $n^{1/2^k} < 2$.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, wrong reflex.

Comment: You have $n$, and you want $k$. Any idea how you could isolate $k$ in the inequality $$n^{1/2^k} < 2\,?$$

Comment: Well, I did this:
$$
\text{Let } x = 1/2^k.
\\
n^x < 2
\\
x < \log_n(2)
\\
\frac{1}{2^k} < \log_n(2)
\\
\frac{1}{\log_n(2)} < 2^k
\\
k > \log_2(\frac{1}{\log_n(2)})
\\
k > -\log_2(\log_n(2))
$$

Comment: It's not a bad start, but you should better take all logarithms to the same basis. Say use $\log_2$ for everything.

Comment: I nailed it!
$$
\\
k > -\log_2(\log_n(2))
\\
k > -\log_2(\frac{\log_2(2)}{\log_2(n)})
\\
k > -\log_2(\frac{\log_2(2)}{\log_2(n)})
\\
k > -\log_2(1) - (-\log_2(\log_2(n)))
\\
k > \log_2(\log_2(n))
$$

Comment: Yup, that's good.